# Excel scatter plot

Tags: excel, graph

Hello and good day to all

I have question related to excel graph. I have some set of values like this

[image]

Now I want to plot these values as a scatter graph. I want to to draw in such a way that by keeping X values same and 4 different Y plots i.e. A, B, C, D in a single graph. Meaning I dont want to merge these Y values on a single X value. Is there any way to do that? I thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The data does not make much sense. All X values are exactly the same, so all data markers will be at exactly the same X position.

To create a scatter chart with multiple series:
- select the data from A1 to B11
- insert a scatter chart
- select the B, C, D ranges (C1 to E11) and copy
- select the chart and use Paste Special > insert as new series with series name in first row

[image]

Since all X values are the same, many data points overlap and are not distinguishable.

Edit after comment: if you do NOT want to plot the values at their true X position (i.e. the value 1.4), then use four pairs of X / Y coordinates. Use X values 1 to 4 with A to D. Then use text boxes to replace the X axis labels or hide the labels and show the legend instead.

[image]

Comment: yes exactly i know. I am working on repetitive measurements and I am checking different parameters on same value. These A, B, C, D are different parameters. I was wondering is there any way that i can draw a  graph with seperate Y parameters on same X point. In short on X axis I have  1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 four times each showing one parameter so that they can be easily distinguishable. As I have alot of values and when I plot as you have plotted the values are not distinguishable even with different markers.

Comment: I added another suggestion